# How to identify GIF images within photo library (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator, gif

Is there a possibility to identify if an image (coming out of the photo library in iOS) is an animated GIF or just a normal photo? I want to show also GIFs inside my app (built with appcelerator titanium), but I need to identify if it's an animated picture first. That's related to the fact that the normal `ImageView` is not able to show animated GIFs, as far as I know - but there are tweaks to show a GIF, nevertheless I need to know that it has to be rendered in this special way instead of using a normal imageView.

Can I read this information somehow out of the image metadata?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this repository](https://github.com/Enouvo/TiGIF/tree/master/iphone). There is a module for Appcelerator.

Comment: Sounds good so far, do you have any experience with this module? What happens if you add a "normal" image to the ImageView - does it show up as usual and only in the case of animated GIFs it's moving?

Comment: I'll do that asap. Thanks a lot for referencing the module, seems to be the right thing. I'll update here when it solved the issue. :)

Comment: I integrated the module and yes, it's working, but the handling is slightly difficult because it only works if you have an already defined "ImageView" component in your view - if you create with Ti.UI.createImageView it doesn't work. What I observed is, that the GIF is playing too slow, it's kind of laggy... Didn't check on real device, but GIF is laggy on simulator.

Comment: what can i say, play with it.